# How to set attributes of drawable resource from the xml including it.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, xml-drawable

Is there any way to set attributes of a defined drawable resource from the xml that is using it. 
Consider the following example:

Say we have the drawable xml file, a shape named "orange_btn" say:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/ripe_orange"/>

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="16dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="16dp" android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>
</shape>
```

and suppose we have some layout xml as containing an image button as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/clouds"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:src="@drawable/orange"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Supposing I would like to change one of the shapes attributes, like the corner radius from within the layout xml, how would i do that?